# How to generate a "big" random number in Python?

Tags: python, random, biginteger

How can I generate a big (more than 64 bits) random integer in Python?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use [`random.getrandbits()`](http://docs.python.org//library/random.html?highlight=random.getrandbits#random.getrandbits):

```
>>> random.getrandbits(128)
117169677822943856980673695456521126221L
```

As stated in the linked documentation, `random.randrange()` will also do the trick if `random.getrandbits()` is available.

Comment: Obvious. Why didn't I think about it? Thank you!

Comment: @dga any solution with *numpy* ?

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher I don't think Numpy supports any integer types bigger than 64 bits. You can store Python objects (including large integers) in Numpy arrays, so you could simply do that, but then you'll lose much of the performance advantage of Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this function to generate a number of any length.

```
def generateRandomNumber(digits):
    finalNumber = ""
    for i in range(digits // 16):
        finalNumber = finalNumber + str(math.floor(random.random() * 10000000000000000))
    finalNumber = finalNumber + str(math.floor(random.random() * (10 ** (digits % 16))))
    return int(finalNumber)
```

Comment: Something smells strange here. What's going on with the hard-coded values (16 and 10**16)? Isn't this going to affect the distribution of the random numbers?

Comment: @Harry not really, I'm multiplying 10**16 to the `random digit` just to remove the decimal digit. as random.random() going to output a random digit of 16 digits with a decimal.