# Python int too large to convert to C

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, sample, integer-overflow

I am running a simple piece of code to return me `batch` number of integers (without replacement) between `0` and `2**63`.

```
from random import sample

batch = 1000
n = 63
rand_nos = sample(range(2**n), batch)
```

I get the error

```
Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

I assume this has got to do with the `random.sample` function internally converting the length of the range to an `int` value. But I could not find any parameter that I could set, to ask the function to use a data type with larger range. How can I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: those are rather large random numbers. What are you using them for?

Comment: I'd rather believe that exception caused by *numpy*

Comment: @MitchWheat I am working on coding theory and have to deal with large codes. This is the dimension of the code that I am working on.

Comment: @OlvinRoght the error exists even without the `np.array` function outside. I'll make it clear by removing the `np` function.

Comment: It can be reproduced by `len(range(2**63))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012534/how-to-generate-a-big-random-number-in-python

Comment: @learner, check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) of `range()`: *"Ranges containing absolute values larger than [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) are permitted but some features (such as [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)) may raise [`OverflowError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OverflowError)."*

Comment: @learner, you can use `randrange()` in list comp as alternative: `rand_nos = [randrange(2**n) for _ in range(batch)]`

Comment: @learner Hope you find some solution in that answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314163/3607051

Comment: Do you really need [0...2^n] interval? Not [0...2^n) aka [0...2^n-1] ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux if you're referring to (2^n) -1 as the upper limit, then yes that would be fine. But 2^(n-1) is not okay. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, you could try to use [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which has some interesting properties - with good choice of constants it will cover whole range [0...2<sup>n</sup>) once without repetition before it hits its period. Thus, it is basically equivalent to sampling without replacement.

Code for n=64, if you need exactly 63, I could dig out set of constant, just ask.

Python 3.9.1, Win10 x64

```
import numpy as np

class LCG(object):

    UZERO: np.uint64 = np.uint64(0)
    UONE : np.uint64 = np.uint64(1)

    def __init__(self, seed: np.uint64, a: np.uint64, c: np.uint64) -> None:
        self._seed: np.uint64 = np.uint64(seed)
        self._a   : np.uint64 = np.uint64(a)
        self._c   : np.uint64 = np.uint64(c)

    def next(self) -> np.uint64:
        self._seed = self._a * self._seed + self._c
        return self._seed

    def seed(self) -> np.uint64:
        return self._seed

    def set_seed(self, seed: np.uint64) -> np.uint64:
        self._seed = seed

    def skip(self, ns: np.int64) -> None:
        """
        Signed argument - skip forward as well as backward

        The algorithm here to determine the parameters used to skip ahead is
        described in the paper F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride,"
        Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). This algorithm is able to skip ahead in
        O(log2(N)) operations instead of O(N). It computes parameters
        A and C which can then be used to find x_N = A*x_0 + C mod 2^M.
        """

        nskip: np.uint64 = np.uint64(ns)

        a: np.uint64 = self._a
        c: np.uint64 = self._c

        a_next: np.uint64 = LCG.UONE
        c_next: np.uint64 = LCG.UZERO

        while nskip > LCG.UZERO:
            if (nskip & LCG.UONE) != LCG.UZERO:
                a_next = a_next * a
                c_next = c_next * a + c

            c = (a + LCG.UONE) * c
            a = a * a

            nskip = nskip >> LCG.UONE

        self._seed = a_next * self._seed + c_next


#%%
np.seterr(over='ignore')

seed = np.uint64(1)

rng64 = LCG(seed, np.uint64(6364136223846793005), np.uint64(1))

print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())

#%%
rng64.skip(-3) # back by 3
print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())
print(rng64.next())

rng64.skip(-3) # back by 3
rng64.skip(2) # forward by 2
print(rng64.next())
```